# How to determine the variation of influences?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, interaction, random-variable, reliability

I need to investigate a chain of influences which can be described as following: First, a deliverer sends barrels of oil. These will be connected to a certain system and purified. Next, the oil will be pumped through a main line throughout the company with several valves. From these, mechanics can fill up oil according to their needs.

As measurements show fluctuations, mainly in a small region but sometimes freaking high, I would like to determine, once and for all, the involved influences. For this, I have the following aspects in mind:

- oil from the oil barrels
- oil from the purification system
- oil from the valves/main line
- oil from the vessel to fill up oil
- oil from the environment (is the vessel closed, sealed, in which environment and so on..)
- oil from the measurement system to analyze the quality of the oil (mainly humidity and particles gathered by a single measurement system)

To do so, I found the so-called [measurement system analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_system_analysis) as well as two packages for it in R (https://www.qualitycontrolwithr.com/package.html, http://www.r-qualitytools.org/) and since the one seems not to be maintained any longer, the following example is something I'd expect in the end:

[image: img]

Is this a reasonable procedure? I'm wondering about the fact that I can't fix a single influence of the "chain".